# How to inject IConfiguration into class which is used as input parameter in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have an endpoint in controller that takes as an argument instance of class `UserQuery`:

```
[HttpGet("[action]")]
public async Task<IActionResult> ProcessUser([FromQuery] UserQuery query)
```

`UserQuery` is a class with a parameterless constructor:

```
public class UserQuery 
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Surname { get; set; }

   UserQuery () {}
}
```

How can I inject an instance of `IConfiguration` into this class?

Comment: Seems to me as a XY-porblem. Can you please elaborate why do you want to do this?

Comment: Because I have values in appsettings.json that I want to use for validation purposes.

Comment: You shouldn't modify a dto object like this. You should map dto to another object that contains business/app logic.

Comment: @tylkonachwile and why do you want to inject it into `UserQuery` exactly? Why not into controller? Or validator?

Comment: Let's imagine I have a key-value pair in appsettings:
allowedAge: 18 and I would like to use this value to validate if age passed by user is higher or not.

Comment: Read your config values in your Startup.cs into a DTO, then services.Add that DTO as a singleton for example. Than just inject it in your controller.

Comment: @tylkonachwile still I do not see why it is needed to be injected in `UserQuery`.

Comment: @mxmissile could you provide an example please?

Comment: @marc_s - typo...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You inject into the controller, not into the DTO,

eg

```
public class MyController
{
   IConfiguration config;
   public MyController(IConfiguration config)
   {
     this.config = config;
   }

   [HttpGet("[action]")]
   public async Task<IActionResult> ProcessUser([FromQuery] UserQuery query)
   {
      //read config and validate query
      ...
   }
```

Comment: thanks, but it is not what I am asking for

Comment: @tylkonachwile but that is what you actually need)